# pass a String array from one activity to another Activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-arrayadapter

I am having two activities in my application. I want to pass tha array of String from one activity to another.. How to pass this values from activity to activity?

Answer (score 2):

```
Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
bundel.putStringArray("key",array);

Intent intent = new Intent(this,next.class)
intent.putExtras(bundel);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thnks! & wht should i do to take the values in the next activity?

Comment: @user2490231  Google?

Comment: `String array[] = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("key");`

Answer (score 0):

First activity:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("strings", array);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second activity:

```
ArrayList<String> resultArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("strings");
```